# Does this consequence of measurability in terms of games of length $\omega+1$ imply measurability?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, large-cardinals

For any two structures $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ in the same first-order language $\mathcal{L}$ and any ordinal $\theta$, let $G_\theta(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ be the two-player game of perfect information of length $\theta$ such that in round $\alpha$ player I plays an element $x_\alpha\in \mathcal{M}$ and then player II plays an element $y_\alpha \in \mathcal{N}$, and player II wins if and only if the augmented structures $(\mathcal{M}, x_\alpha)_{\alpha < \theta}$ and $(\mathcal{N}, y_\alpha)_{\alpha < \theta}$ have the same theory in the language obtained from $\mathcal{L}$ by adding $\theta$ constant symbols.

Note that if there is an elementary embedding $j$ of $\mathcal{M}$ into $\mathcal{N}$ then player II has winning strategies in $G_\theta(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ for all $\theta$ obtained by letting $y_\alpha = j(x_\alpha)$.  Conversely, if player II has a winning strategy in $G_\theta(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ where $\theta$ is the cardinality of $\mathcal{M}$ then we may obtain an elementary embedding of $\mathcal{M}$ into $\mathcal{N}$ by letting $j(x_\alpha) = y_\alpha$ where $(x_\alpha:\alpha < \theta)$ is an enumeration of $\mathcal{M}$.  The existence of a winning strategy for player II in the case $\theta = \omega$ is weaker: it is equivalent to the existence of an elementary embedding of $\mathcal{M}$ into $\mathcal{N}$ in every generic extension of $V$ by the poset $\text{Col}(\omega,\mathcal{M})$.

Let us define a cardinal $\kappa$ to be *$\theta$-strategically measurable* if
there is an ordinal $\kappa'$ and a transitive set $N$ such that $\kappa < \kappa' \in N$ and letting $\mathcal{M} = (H_{\kappa^+}; \mathord{\in},\kappa, \xi)_{\xi < \kappa}$ and $\mathcal{N} = (N; \mathord{\in}, \kappa', \xi)_{\xi < \kappa}$, player II has a winning strategy in the game $G_\theta(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$.

Remarks:

1. $2^\kappa$-strategic measurability is equivalent to measurability.
2. If $0^\sharp$ exists then every Silver indiscernible is $\omega$-strategically measurable in $L$. (Use $j:L \to L$ and the absoluteness of existence of winning strategies for closed games of length $\omega$).
3. Every $(\omega+1)$-strategically measurable cardinal is a Ramsey cardinal and a limit of Ramsey cardinals. (Proof given below.)

Questions:

1. Is ($\omega+1$)-strategic measurability equivalent to measurability?
2. If not, what is its consistency strength?
3. Have these games been studied before for $\theta > \omega$? Do they have a name?

Proof of remark 3:

We use a winning strategy for player II in the game $G_{\omega+1}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ (or just the nonexistence of a winning strategy for player I) to build increasing sequences $(M_n, n<\omega)$ and $(\mu_n, n<\omega)$ such that $M_n \prec H_{\kappa^+}$, $\left| M_n\right| = \kappa$, $\mu_n$ is an $M_n$-normal ultrafilter on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)\cap M_n$, and $M_n, \mu_n \in M_{n+1}$. In round $n$ player I plays an enumeration of $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)\cap M_n$ in order type $\kappa$ and uses player II's response to define $\mu_n$.  Then letting $M_\omega = \bigcup_{n<\omega}M_n$ and $\mu_\omega = \bigcup_{n<\omega} \mu_n$, we see that $\mu_\omega$ is a weakly amenable $M_\omega$-normal ultrafilter on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)\cap M_\omega$.  Moreover it is countably complete (in the sense of nonempty intersection) because otherwise player I can win by playing a counterexample to countable completeness in round $\omega$. Since we can take $M_0$ to contain any given subset of $\kappa$, it follows that $\kappa$ is a Ramsey cardinal. Because $M_\omega \prec H_{\kappa^+}$ we can reflect Ramseyness below $\kappa$.

(See [Gitman, Ramsey-like cardinals](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/ramseylike-cardinals/2DA3A9DBB58192B78025E950E9601742) for the relationship between Ramsey cardinals and weakly amenable countably complete ultrafilters.)

Further remarks:

1. The proof of Ramseyness outlined above resembles the "filter games" introduced by [Holy and Schlicht](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10043.pdf) and further studied by [Nielsen and Welch](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10383.pdf).
2. Defining ($\omega+1$)-strategic strongness in an analogous way, I think I can prove that it is equiconsistent with strongness. (<s>And again the argument only requires the nonexistence of a winning strategy for player I.</s> *The previous sentence is wrong; I will add more details later.*)  However, the proof goes through ${\bf\Sigma}^1_4$ generic absoluteness and does not seem to generalize to other strategic large cardinals.

Comment: Being $\omega+1$-strategically measurable implies that the "nonempty" player has a winning strategy in the Mycielski game (cut and choose). Thus, it is at least equiconsistency to a measurable cardinal (see "The evolution of large cardinals axiom in set theory" by Kanamori and Magidor, section 27).

Comment: I see!  That essentially answers half of the questions.  I wonder if one can show it is not equivalent to measurability by a forcing argument.

Comment: @YairHayut Do you think you could write out the argument with the Mycielski game as an answer?

Answer (score 10):

This answer addresses only the consistency strength of $\omega+1$-strategically measurable.

**Claim:** If there is a $\omega+1$-strategically measurable cardinal then there is an inner model with a measurable cardinal.

**Proof:** A winning strategy for $G_{\omega+1}(H(\kappa^{+}), \mathcal{N})$ for some transitive $\mathcal{N}$ as in the definition of $\omega+1$-measurability implies that there is a winning strategy for the Mycielski game (the "cut and choose" game) on $\kappa$.

In the Mycielski game, a sequence of subsets of $\kappa$ $A_0, A_1, \dots, A_n, \dots$ in constructed in the following way. Let us denote $A_{-1} = \kappa$. At step $n < \omega$, player I picks a partition of $A_{n-1}$ into two sets $B_n, C_n$ (so $B_n \cup C_n = A_{n-1}$) and player II chooses one of them to be $A_n$. Player II wins if $|\bigcap_{n < \omega} A_n| > 1$.

Given a winning strategy for the game $G_{\omega+1}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$, where $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ are as in the question, we can construct a winning strategy for the Mycielski game as follows. Player II will maintain an auxiliary play in the game $G_{\omega+1}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$.

At step $n < \omega$, let $(B_n, C_n)$ be the partition that player I played. Player II define $x_n = (B_n, C_n)$ and use the winning strategy of $G_{\omega+1}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ in order to produce some $y_n \in \mathcal{N}$.

Clearly, $y_n = (B_n^\star, C_n^\star)$. Now, player II will pick $A_n$ to be $B_n$ iff $\kappa \in B_n^\star$ (and then $A_n^\star = B_n^\star$. Otherwise, $A_n^\star = C_n^\star$). We want to make sure that player II wins.

Indeed, in the constructed play in the game $G_{\omega+1}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$, we obtained the sequence of steps $\langle x_n, y_n \mid n < \omega\rangle$. Player II can ask what the winning strategy will answer to $x_{\omega} = \langle A_n \mid n < \omega\rangle$. Let $y_\omega$ be the answer. Then, by elementarity $y_n = \langle A_n^\star \mid n < \omega\rangle$. Now, since $\kappa \in \bigcap A_n^\star$, $\bigcap A_n$ cannot be bounded in $\kappa$.

It is known that the existence of a winning strategy for player II in the Mycielski game is equiconsistent with a measurable cardinal (see "The evolution of large cardinals axiom in set theory" by Kanamori and Magidor, section 27. The argument is attributed there to Silver and Solovay). **QED**

Let me remark that it is consistent to have a winning strategy for the Mycielski game at accessible cardinals. For example, it is consistent there is a winning strategy for the Mycielski game on $\omega_2$.

Comment: Great, Yair! Thank you.

Comment: Yair, there's a detail in the proof of the Silver-Solovay fact you mentioned that I don't quite understand. Do you know why the ultrapower in their proof is wellfounded, as they're only considering functions which are elements of their set $A$? And if their ultrapower is really just $\text{Ult}(A,U)$ then I don't see why that should give a generic embedding $j:V\to M$. This is on page 249 in the book you referenced.

Comment: Assume that the ultrapower is ill-founded. Let $\dot{f} = \langle \dot{f}_n \mid n < \omega\rangle$ be a name for an infinite decreasing sequence of ordinals. Let $M$ be a countable elementary sub-model of $H(\theta)$ for large $\theta$ containing the name $\dot{f}$. Let $H$ be an $M$-generic filter and let $U$ be the corresponding $M$-ultrafilter. Note that $B_n = \{\alpha \in A\mid f_{n+1}(\alpha) \in f_n(\alpha)\} \in U$ and by the definition of $U$, $B = \bigcap B_n \neq \emptyset$. Let $x\in B$. Then $f_n(x)$ is an infinite decreasing sequence of ordinals - a contradiction.

Comment: @YairHayut Thank you! I'm wondering though, why is the intersection of the $B_n$'s nonempty? Since the sequence $\langle B_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ isn't in $V$, so this seems to use that $U$ is also countably complete in $M[H]$? But, letting $\langle X_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ be a sequence of bounded subsets of $A$ which is cofinal in $A$, we get that $A-X_n\in U$ for all $n<\omega$, so $\emptyset\in U$, contradicting that $U$ is a filter?

Comment: I wrote this in a slightly confusing way, sorry. The $B_n$ are defined inside $M[H]$ and not $V[G]$ (the sequence of $f_n$ at this point of the argument is the interpretation of $M[H]$ to the name $\dot{f}$, and not the sequence of functions in $V[G]$). In particular, since $M, H\in V$ also the sequence $\langle B_n \mid n < \omega\rangle \in V$ and thus has non empty intersection in $V$.

Comment: @YairHayut Ah! That makes sense. Quite a neat trick! :)
Also, so it seems that they *are* really forming the full ultrapower $\text{Ult}(V,U)$, using all functions in $V$, and not just in $A$ as they write in their argument, right?

Comment: Yes. I think that they mean that they construct the ultrapower using all functions $f \colon A \to V$ from $V$ and not $V[G]$.